# How to open new window for iOS 5+

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, mobile-safari

The title is pretty self explanatory. The issue i'm having is that window.open will only seem to open links in a new tab instead of a "new window" or a new instance of mobile safari. I've tried every little hack/trick I can think of, but it always just opens it in a new tab. Am I missing something or am I going to have to go native to work around this?

Comment: Mobile Safari doesn't have multiple windows, and iOS apps don't have a notion of multiple instances of an application. What do you expect to happen here?

Comment: Yea I know, I was just hoping that maybe someone knew something I didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Safari on iOS only has one window in one process (and the same goes with basically any other iOS app). You can't open a page in another instance or window, only a new tab.

You can't work around this in native code using App Store-approved SDK methods either, not in Safari nor in your own application. It's just not the way iOS apps work.

Comment: Can't work around this natively? Are you sure? I'm sure *something* could be hacked together (though I concede it's sort of a ridiculous idea and a massive waste of time).

Comment: @Jezen Thomas: Good point. Jailbreakers can come up with anything these days. I've just clarified that part of my answer.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I figured as much. Thanks for clarifying.